# What's the best way to log Core Data NSManagedObject IDs on creation?

Tags: iphone, core-data

I've dealt with a couple errors recently in which I will get an exception that mentions a managed object by URI. The URI is somewhat helpful. It looks kind of like x-coredata://blahblahblahblahblah/EntityName/p22. At least I can tell what type of entity the problem occurred on, but I have not as yet been able to track it down to a particular object. So far I've been able to debug the problems without figuring that out.

I imagine I could track it down. I could probably open up the database and do SQL queries until I found something that matched up to something in the URL. However that seems like kind of a lot of trouble, and also not very efficient if I have to debug a problem that happens on a beta tester's or deployed user's device. So I think it would be nice to log the object ID URI when the object is created, along with some properties I can recognize the object by.

Should be simple, right? Just right after I create an object in my code I do an NSLog something like

```
NSLog(@"Created Foo instance: %@", [foo.objectID URIRepresentation]);
```

Only problem is, the URIs I;m getting don't look like the above. They look more like x-coredata:///EntityName/blahblahblahblahblah. I realized I'm probably getting temporary IDs.

So, how can I match that up with the permanent ID? If I could find out a hook where I can just put a log message saying "Object with temporary ID %@ reassigned permanent ID %@" that would be all I need.

Comment: I think something like "x-coredata://blahblahblahblahblah/EntityName/p22" (the p22 part) is the objectID in the CoreData entity (the permanent one) which you can get just NSLog'ing the objectID message

Comment: to get the numeric id you could just take the last part of the objectID and strip the alpha part. I.e., take "p22" and get "22" which will correspond to the z_pk in your sqlite database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I question the value of this but it is possible via two methods in the `NSManagedObject` itself.

First, set up a transient `NSString` either directly in the model or in the subclass.  Then override the following methods:

```
- (void)willSave
{
  if (![[self objectID] isTemporaryID]) return;
  [self setTemporaryIDString:[[[self objectID] URIRepresentation] absoluteString]];
}

- (void)didSave
{
  if (![self temporaryIDString]) return;

  NSLog(@"%@ moved to %@", [self temporaryIDString], [[[self objectID] URIRepresentation] absoluteString]);
  [self setTemporaryIDString:nil];
}
```

Comment: If you question the value of it I'm open to other suggestions for how to debug exceptions that refer to an objectID.

Comment: I usually capture them in the debugger and interrogate the objects while they are alive.  At worst I will spit the entire object out to the console via `NSLog(@"Object %@", someMO);`

Answer (score 1):

Core Data NSManagedObject has a property debugDescription, use it.

```
NSManagedObject * customer = nil;

NSLog(@"customer : %@", customer.debugDescription);
```